# Using join method on Entity Framework cause trouble

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

when I use join for listing data from the database by string array.

This is my code:

```
public List<tbl_Customer> Getcustomers(string [] Vouchers) // Vouchers length 1700
{
    try
    {
        using (TurkusDEntities _db = new TurkusDEntities())
        {
            return _db.tbl_Customer
                      .Where(c => c.fldStatus != 0)
                      .Join(Vouchers, c => c.fldVoucher, k => k, (c,k ) => c)
                      .ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`tbl_Customer` has more than 50,000 rows. If I do not use join method, working without any error. With join method, the code should return around 5,000 rows.

Comment: EF do not support Join with local collection. Use `Contains` for filtering.

Comment: You should rarely use Join in LINQ to Entities.  Instead use Include if you want related entities.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for response but  `Contains` not useful. Need for each loop also it is risk on 50.000 record mean Voucher numbers can be like AB-123 and AB-1234. So when i use `Contains` can return wrong results.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for your response but I can not use Include when comparing with tables in database with `string [] Vouchers`. I found a solition i will answer my question by my self.

Answer (score 0):

After long research, I found the following solution. I was getting an error when I wanted to use `join` with the `string [] Vouchers` i created under certain conditions.Instead of `string [] Vouchers` i used `join` without create any variable or model like the following codes.

```
model.Customers = _db.tbl_Customer.Where(c => c.fldStatus != 0)
///start
                    .Join(_db.tbl_Reservation
                    .Where(c => c.fldTourDateTime >= start && c.fldTourDateTime <= finish && c.fldStatus != 0)
                    .Join(_db.tbl_ResAccount.Where(k => k.fldStatus != 0), z => z.fldReservation, y => y.fldReservationNumber, (z, y) => z)
                    .Select(c=>c.fldVoucher)
/// finish  
                    ,c => c.fldVoucher, k => k, (c, k) => c)
                    .ToList();
```

I was creating `string [] Vouchers` with conditions between start and finish.